# How do I do the check once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a condition that should check whether it is true or false. I did this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Slot.SlotBool == true)
    {
        score++;
        Debug.Log("OK! " + score);
    }
}
```

But I want him to check without pressing the button, and put it in Update(), but then Score was increasing every second... Is there any other way to do it?

I have 3 scripts, the first one is needed to move an object, get a starting position, etc. It looks like this:

```
public class DManager : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public static GameObject objBeingDraged;

    private Vector2 startPosition;
    private Transform startParent;
    private CanvasGroup canvasGroup;
    private Transform itemDraggerParent;

    void Start()
    {
        canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        itemDraggerParent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ItemDraggerParent").transform;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        objBeingDraged = gameObject;

        startPosition = transform.position;
        startParent = transform.parent;
        transform.SetParent(itemDraggerParent);
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        objBeingDraged = null;

        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
        if (transform.parent == itemDraggerParent)
        {
            transform.position = startPosition;
            transform.SetParent(startParent);
        }
    }
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0,0, -90);
    }
}
```

The second one is needed so that when the object is released:

```
public class Puzzle : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (DManager.objBeingDraged == null) return;
        DManager.objBeingDraged.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
}
```

And the third one is needed already in order to get an object and compare the resulting object name. I could put score accruals here, but here he checks every element

```
int score=0;

public static bool f=false;
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (!item)
    {
        item = DManager.objBeingDraged;
       
        if (item.name== this.gameObject.name)
        {
            if (item.transform.rotation == this.gameObject.transform.rotation)
            {
                f = true;
                Debug.Log(f);
                score++;
                Debug.Log(score);
            }
        }

        item.transform.SetParent(transform);
        item.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
void Update()
{
    if (item != null && item.transform.parent != transform)
    {
        item = null;
    }
}
```

So I created another script where points are already awarded

Comment: You can add a member that holds the last value of `Slot.SlotBool` - e.g. `lastSlotBool` and then apply the increment only if `(Slot.SlotBool == true) && (Slot.SlotBool != lastSlotBool)`.

Comment: @wohlstad, and why the last value? and it will still be in the update() method, the score will increase

Comment: After you do the increment, update `lastSlotBool`. Then the next call to `Update()` will not  get into the `if` because then `Slot.SlotBool == lastSlotBool`.

Comment: when do you want to increase the score...? you can't just ask if there is another way to do it.

Comment: @wohlstad,  I tried it as you advised, but for some reason the score is still increasing

Comment: @jkimishere,  and I wrote the condition, if the received value is == true, then the score increases

Comment: If you'll post a [mre], we might be able to help you further.

Comment: if you put the if statement inside update, it will call *every frame*. you could create a method for incrementing the score and call it if you want.

Comment: @wohlstad, I updated the question, threw it off in more detail, please take a look?

Comment: @jkimishere, that's why I asked the question, how can I do it differently

Comment: @AvgustKuk I see that you set `f = true;` after you increment the score. But where do you check the value of `f` ? You should check it before doing increment, so that it will happen once (`if (f==false) { ... increment ... }`). I guess you also need to reset `f` to `false` somewhere in order to allow to increase the score at some time.

Comment: @wohlstad, The value of F, I check in a separate script is: void Update()
{ if (Slot.F== true)
{ score++; Debug.Log("OK! " + score); } . and where should it be written "if (f==false) { ... increment ... }"? in the Update method or create another method or something else?

Comment: Whereever you increment the `score` - check `f` and do it only if `f==false` (and set `f=true` if you increment - like in your code above).

Comment: @wohlstad, it turned out, thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

you can add another boolean to check if the score was already incremented.

```
    private bool incrementedBool = false;
    void Update()
    {
        if(incrementedBool == false)
        {
            incrementedBool = true;
            if (Slot.SlotBool == true)
            {
                score++;
                Debug.Log("OK! " + score);
            }
        }
        
     }
```

Then, if you want to incremente another time the score for any reason, you can reset the boolean like that :

```
incrementedBool = false;
```